# How to enable the user to input a number and for the program to search it in a binary search in discord

Tags: python, discord, binary-search

My code needs to use binary search to search if the user has inputted any of the following numbers in the binary search. I am not the best at implementing it into discord . Just need to make it work for discord.

Tried doing it without the discord commands and it works however I want people to use my discord bot and to be able to do it online.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.upper().startswith('Number'):
        await client.send_message(message.channel, ((int(input"What number do you choose 1 to 100"))))

        numbers = [6,7,34,43,88,64]
        numbers.sort()


async def BinarySearch (numbers, wanted):
    found = False
    first = 0
    last = len(numbers)-1
    while (first <= last) and found == False:
        midpoint = (first + last) // 2
        if numbers[midpoint] ==wanted:
            found = True
        else:
            if wanted < numbers[midpoint]:
                last = midpoint -1
            else:
                first = midpoint + 1
    return found

if BinarySearch(numbers, wanted) == True:
    print("I Found Your NUMBER!!!")
else:
    print("no u, do it again!")
```

If the numbers [6,7,34,43,88,64] arent imputted by the user then the bot says it wrong numbers if it does then the bot will say well done found your number.

Answer (score 0):

`message.contents.upper()` can never start with "Number". It may start with "NUMBER". I'm guessing your if statement is not running.

Try putting a log message in the if statement and check.

Comment: Thanks I changed it however 
 File "F:/YUGIOHSQL/PRACTISE.py", line 34, in <module>
    if BinarySearch(numbers, wanted) == True:
NameError: name 'numbers' is not defined

Comment: `numbers` is defined as a local variable. If you want to pass it between functions either add it as an argument or make it a global.

Comment: thanks b defined it globally same with wanted but now   File "F:/YUGIOHSQL/PRACTISE.py", line 37
    if BinarySearch(numbers, wanted) == True:
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'BinarySearch' was never awaited

Comment: See this for that error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48790427/why-it-says-fetch-function-was-never-awaited

Comment: how do i link if message.content.upper().startswith('NUMBERS'):
        await client.send_message(message.channel, ("What number do you choose 1 to 100"))

    so the user is able to type in the number they want and it checks in the binary search